# QGIS polygonize GDAL DLL load failed

Tags: qgis, gdal, polygonize

I'm using QGIS 2.6.1 and i've been having problems using the polygonize function.

I keep getting a "DLL load failed" import error. I've searched older threads which unfortunately weren't able to help. I tried resetting the GDAL executable path to `C:/OSGeo4W/bin/osgPlugins-3.0.0`, and the python path to: `C:/Program Files/QGIS Brighton/apps/Python27/Lib/site-packages/osgeo`.

I don't get this problem when I try to use other functions (Rasterize or Extraction-Contour, for example). So i'm not sure whether it's a problem with the path or something else. Any ideas?

> Traceback (most recent call last): 
>   File "C:\Program Files\QGISBR~1\bin\gdal_polygonize.py", line 36, in 
>   import gdal, ogr, osr 
>   File "C:\Program Files\QGIS Brighton\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py", line 26, in 
>   _gdal = swig_import_helper() 
>   File "C:\Program Files\QGIS Brighton\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py", line 22, in swig_import_helper 
>   _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description) 
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.